# Show name of columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have three date values in my table, namely ActivationDate, RegistrationDate, and CreationDate and I would like to have a select to show the name of column with least value.

I used

> Select LEAST(ActivationDate, RegistrationDate, CreationDate) from table name

and it returns the smallest value. However, I want to know which of these three is the smallest value. So, my expected outcome is the name of the column that has least date which can be activation date, registration date or creation date.

For your solution, kindly state what would be the result if 3 of them have similar values? Does it return all or one?

Thanks

Comment: Play around with DATEDIFF SQL function, see if that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to test the `least` value against each column, in a conditional statement.

Assuming the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `activationdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `registrationdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `creationdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL
)
```

with these values

```
mysql> select * from test;
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| activationdate      | registrationdate    | creationdate        |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-02 00:00:00 | 2015-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 2015-01-30 00:00:00 | 2015-01-15 00:00:00 | 2015-01-12 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

You can use the following query to extract the smallest of the values, and the column name:

```
 select least(activationdate, registrationdate, creationdate) as value,
        case when least(activationdate, registrationdate, creationdate) = activationdate then 'activationdate' 
             when least(activationdate, registrationdate, creationdate) = registrationdate then 'registrationdate'
             when least(activationdate, registrationdate, creationdate) = creationdate then 'creationdate'
        end as field
   from test;
```

and it will give you these results:

```
+---------------------+----------------+
| value               | field          |
+---------------------+----------------+
| 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | activationdate |
| 2015-01-12 00:00:00 | creationdate   |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fetch all three minimal values:

```
SELECT MIN(ActivationDate), MIN(RegistrationDate), MIN(CreationDate) from table name
```

and after that, by java/php or whatever you're using, take smallest value

Comment: It does not do what I expect. I wanted minimum of 3 for each record. But this one shows the minimum of a single column for the entire database. Anyway, thanks.